# What is the proper expression of anglewise comparison?

Tags: expressions

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this, so please correct me if I should post it somewhere else.

I compare my data, along the angle. That is, I collect data in 10-20, 20-30, 30-40 ... degrees, and in each sector I compare the data with my model.

I say this is **anglewise comparison**, but I'm not sure this is the right way to express it.

---

Context:

I have data distributed in this manner.

[image]

And I made a model for the data. I want to compare the model and data by direction. That is, collect the data in 15-35 degrees, 35-55 degress, and compare the data and the model like this:

[image]

The histogram is the data binned in that direction, and the black curve is the model. How should I name this comparison?

Sectoral comparison? Directional comparison?

Comment: I would guess at "angular comparison", rather than "anglewise", but I think that if this word exists, it will be very specific to the context of your work, whatever it is, and so you should ask in a forum related to your work.

Comment: I think it would help a lot to have some idea of what you are measuring.  Is it how often the wind comes from that direction?  Is it a population density in that sector from a given center point?  Is it how much friction there is between a brake pad and disc on that setion of the disc?  Context is everything.

Comment: @cobaltduck, I compare the probability density function(pdf) and cumulative distribution function(cdf) for each sector. I compare the PDF and CDF of data and the model that I created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a *sectorized* domain (an established adjective but a dubious verb). Comparing your model to data on a sector by sector basis is termed a **sectoral comparison**. Making a comparison between different sectors is a **cross-sectoral comparison**, however, sectoral comparison is also used in this manner.

> 1995-2020 49 3.5 Comparison of C02 emissions baseline forecasting:
>   TAIGEM®-D model and Taiwan-MARKAL model 50 3.6 Sectoral comparison of
>   C02 emissions baseline forecasting: TAIGEM®-D model and Taiwan-MARKAL

Global Warming and the Asian Pacific
edited by Ching-Cheng Chang, Robert O. Mendelsohn, Daigee Shaw

It is more commonly used in the sense of market sectors, not geometric sectors, but no matter, this is the technical term for what you are doing. The domain within a sector is a sectoral patch.

Comment: An additional thought. Can I say directional comparison? Because I binned the data into different directions and compare them. For example, I bin the data ranging from 0-20 degree, and compare the model and the original data distribution.

Comment: Not really. You aren't comparing directions. You are comparing stuff binned on the basis of direction. Either you compare the same patch generated by two different models, or two different patches generated by the same model. Work with the stuff. The map can be described separately.

Comment: I have update the context above. Could you take a look at that again? And should I still call it sectoral comparison?

Comment: Try number 2.  What I think I'm looking at is a series of velocity charts each representing the velocity distribution of one sector. So the collection of charts show a sector by sector comparison of the model's performance. The individual charts are sectoral comparisons.

Comment: OK. So the individual should be called sectoral comparison. The collection should be called cross-sectoral comparison?

Comment: No, a comparison between two sectors is a cross-sectoral comparison. The collection isn't. They are a collection of sectoral charts.

Comment: Then what should I call them? I need a title for that in my paper. And what does the `number 2` you mean?